# How do I create a resumable file upload using django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-file-upload

The question is stated above. While there are many tutorials about file upload using django rest framework. None mentioned about the resumable version of it. And I need to implement it for a project. Can someone point me to some resources or give a sample code? Help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

This is what I have gotten so far.

**views.py**

```
class FileUploadView(views.APIView):
    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser)

    def put(self, request, format=None):
        file_obj = request.data['file']
        self.handle_uploaded_file(file_obj)
        return Response(status=204)

    def handle_uploaded_file(self, ufile):
        filename = "{0}/{1}".format(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, ufile)
        with open(filename, "wb+") as target:
            for chunk in ufile.chunks():
                target.write(chunk)
```

**curl command**

```
curl -H "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=try.py" -X PUT -F "file=@try.py" http://localhost:8000/api/fileupload/?filename=testing
```

**try.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase

# Create your tests here.
```

The next part is how to make it resumable.

Comment: Consider [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249042/uploading-large-files-with-python-django)

Comment: @Ross Rogers, I have tried that. but getting errors. that method worked well for a form submission. But what I wanna create is an API for file upload.

Comment: Can you create a backend for [Resumable.js?](http://resumablejs.com/)

Comment: @Ross Rogers, No I need to decouple my frontend from backend. this API is not only used web browser, it will needs to be used by mobile devices too.

Anyway, I managed to do a file upload, but the file is not being parsed properly. the header is saved together with the file.

Comment: If you create the backend API surface for Resumable.js, you can still use that same API on other platforms and not connect directly with Resuamble.js.  You'll just be following a pattern that others have used.