# Is it possible to pause and resume an http file upload?

Tags: python, django, file-upload

My application needs heavy files(>=20GB) to be uploaded to the server. Can we pause and resume an upload made through http?

I am using Django to build my application.

Comment: This might help you: https://github.com/juliomalegria/django-chunked-upload & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249042/uploading-large-files-with-python-django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could split up the files to chunks and upload them? Take a look at this: https://gist.github.com/nbari/7335384

Comment: Yes, I am using resumable.js to upload the file in chunks and resume upload when the connection is lost or paused.