# Django: Uploading a file to a REST API with a FileField in a model

Tags: python, django, rest, api, filefield

So here is the context. I am using Django with Python3.6, and we're using Django REST Framework to build our REST API. I have a simple form on a page, but it is not submitted directly. I am calling manually our API using axios.

Here's the code used when pressing the submit button:

```
let form = new FormData();
form.append('name', this.game.name);
form.append('video', this.game.video);
form.append('icon', this.game.icon);

axios.post("api/games/", form, {headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
}})
```

Everything is fine here. My API receive the correct data, I can create my game object easily.

The main issue is the 'video' field. It is registered as a FileField in my models.py

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
icon = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
video = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

When submitting an MP4 video file (.mp4) that is like 500ko, it is working properly.

But when I try to upload a file that is much greater, like 5 mo and with format QT (.mov), I got an error from django:

```
ERROR 2017-11-23 16:59:31,831 exception Internal Server Error: /api/games/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 90, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 489, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 449, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 486, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 21, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 26, in perform_create
    serializer.save()
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 214, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "myawesomeproject/api/serializers.py", line 114, in create
    return super().create(validated_data)
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 913, in create
    instance = ModelClass.objects.create(**validated_data)
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 394, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 808, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 838, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 924, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 963, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1076, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1106, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1059, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1059, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1058, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1008, in pre_save_val
    return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 296, in pre_save
    file.save(file.name, file.file, save=False)
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 94, in save
    self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 54, in save
    return self._save(name, content)
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 338, in _save
    file_move_safe(content.temporary_file_path(), full_path)
  File "myawesomeproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/move.py", line 58, in file_move_safe
    with open(old_file_name, 'rb') as old_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/wc/6cny2lg147l55mt4zm92zw9m0000gn/T/tmp6xuujgz2.upload'
```

I read online that Django is handling files differently depending on their size which leads me to believe that it comes from that.

But besides some information, I couldn't find any solutions to my problem.

Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249042/uploading-large-files-with-python-django

Comment: Thanks, that is the question that I've already seen, I see how it can help, but I don't know how to use that in order to update the FileField of my model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed my issue. I made a terrible mistake, sorry about that.

I was renaming my file in the validation step. The thing is that it worked for the images and videos that are <2.5Mb so I didn't thought it could be coming from it.

To fix it, I removed the renaming in my validator, and just edited the method I set in the upload_to parameter of my FileField.