# WORKER TIMEOUT critical

Tags: nginx

I am trying to upload a video of size 8GB in ubuntu server 18.04
project is based on django 
while uploading it'll upload till 100% then error popups saying 404 page not found error ,
If i'm, uploading 2Gb video it is getting uploaded without any error .

Comment: Also i defind this nginx configuration file client_max_body_size 0;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading large files with Python/Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249042/uploading-large-files-with-python-django)