# How to fix Django ImageField upload error on admin panel?

Tags: django

I have a model in django named `MainPagePicture`:

```
class MainPagePicture(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery/', null=False)
```

When I try to upload a big image (**1 MB and bigger**) using admin panel I get this error:

[image]

I have no problem with small images (I tried **30 Kb and 16 KB** Images) and it works good.
my `admin.py` class is:

```
@admin.register(MainPagePicture)
class MainPagePictureAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model = MainPagePicture
```

My Django version is 3.1.6 and pillow version is 8.1.0 and Database is PostgreSQL.

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249042/uploading-large-files-with-python-django#:~:text=Django%20will%20by%20default%2C%20put,are%20available%20in%20the%20documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not solve the problem