# upload huge file and receive that with django framework for example

Tags: python, django, file-upload, microservices, django-celery

I want to send huge file from http request and receive that in django application,
how can I do this?
please describe to me the scenario.
Do I must split the file or there is some other way to solve that?

i want to test that with celery...

Comment: What is the size of your huge file?

Comment: about 5GB @lucasGrugru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of Django explains how to make basically what you do: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#file-uploads

For large files, Django will not upload in memory but put in `/tmp`, it is different from classic file upload Django usage.

You have to increase the file size limit, set by settings:

```
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 5*1024*1024*1024 # make it 5GB instead of 2Mb
```

I suggest, maybe, using a library like https://github.com/juliomalegria/django-chunked-upload if you want to make a good user experience. Sending in chunks and allowing users to resume..etc

You can find more information on this StackOverflow topic: [Uploading large files with Python/Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249042/uploading-large-files-with-python-django)