What is the best way to handle potentially large file uploads in django?
I've been reading the django docs and posts here on stackoverflow but still not sure how to. So far this is my code:
forms.py:
def validate_file(file):
    # Validate if no file submitted
    if not file:
        #raise ValidationError("No file submitted")
        raise ValidationError("Error")

    # Check file size (5 GB limit)
    max_size = 5 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024  # 5 GB in bytes
    if file.size > max_size:
        #raise ValidationError("The maximum file size that can be uploaded is 5GB")
        raise ValidationError("Error")
    
    # Define allowed file types and their corresponding MIME types
    allowed_types = {
        # Audio formats
        'wav': ['audio/wav', 'audio/x-wav'],
        'mp3': ['audio/mpeg', 'audio/mp3'],
        'mpga': ['audio/mpeg'],
        'aac': ['audio/aac'],
... 

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField(validators=[validate_file])

views.py:
def transcribe_Submit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']

            session_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
            request.session['session_id'] = session_id

            try:
                transcribed_doc, created = TranscribedDocument.objects.get_or_create(id=session_id)
                transcribed_doc.audio_file = uploaded_file
                transcribed_doc.save()
...

modesl.py:
class TranscribedDocument(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length = 40)
    audio_file = models.FileField(max_length = 140, upload_to='example_upload_url/', null= True)
...

This is what I've been working with but I've been reading that it is better to handle uploads as chunks so that large files don't overwhelm the website.
The website uploads to directly DigitalOcean Spaces with no files stored on the server and the maximum file upload size allowed by my website is 10GB if that is important.

Please clarify your question. Does your code not work? Or are you wondering how to handle it as chunks? "The best way" is subjective - maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249042/uploading-large-files-with-python-django would help.

Yes it works. But I'm wondering the I should handle it as chunks and if so, how.

If you are handling the request, the file is uploaded already. You might want to implement your own upload handler to stop the upload earlier.

@KlausD. Not sure I understand. Do you mean I should replace the existing code that I have written to handle file uploads with a custom file upload handler that can handle large files?
